# How to set a table's field to autonumber using a query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a db that has been using social security numbers as the unique ID, and I was hoping to be able to change it so that it could display a unique ID without relying on the SSN. Some tables aren't completely consistent when I took a look.

The only solution I can think up is that I can connect the tables by ssn, but have a autonumber unique ID to join with the ssn... so I can display the autonumber instead of the ssn.

For easier illustration:

```
Table 1:
+ ------ + --------- +
| SSN    | FirstName |
+ ------ + --------- +
| 111111 | Jeff      |
| 123456 | Kevin     |
| 654321 | Mark      |
| 555555 | David     |
+ ------ + --------- +

Table 2:
+ ------ + ---------- +
| SSN    | Address    |
+ ------ + ---------- +
| 111111 | California |
| 123456 | Texas      |
| 654321 | Arizona    |
+ ------ + ---------- +

FakeIDTable:
+ --- + -- +
| SSN | ID |
+ --- + -- +
```

This Query:

```
SELECT Table1.FirstName, Table2.Address, FakeIDTable.ID
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SSN = Table2.SSN)
LEFT JOIN FakeIDTable ON Table1.SSN = FakeIDTable.SSN;
```

Gives this Result:

```
+ --------- + ---------- + -- +
| FirstName | Address    | ID |
+ --------- + ---------- + -- +
| Jeff      | California |    |
| Kevin     | Texas      |    |
| Mark      | Arizona    |    |
+ --------- + ---------- + -- |
```

Is it possible to populate FakeIDTable.ID with an autonumber using Sql?

```
Update Query1
Set Query1.ID = (autonumber)
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a column with the [**`identity()`** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) property to the table where `ssn` is unique for that table and contains all referenced `ssn`s, or create a table that just has the unique `ssn`s and an `id`, or number some rows using `row_number()`:

Adding an `identity` column to an existing table that does not have an `identity` column:

```
alter table t
  add Id int not null identity(1,1);
```

Creating a fake table with an `identity` column:

```
create table faketable (
    id  int not null identity(1,1) primary key
  , ssn int not null unique
  );

insert into faketable (ssn)
  select distinct ssn
  from t;
```

Updating a non-identity Id using `row_number()` using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (order by ssn)
  from t
)
update cte
  set Id = rn;
```

Updating a non-identity Id using `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
update sub
set Id = rn
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (order by ssn)
  from t
) as sub
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TDDA51123

Comment: @DanBracuk Yep. If there was an Id column on the table that was not an `identity` column, you can update it using `row_number()` using a cte or a subquery. demo: http://rextester.com/TDDA51123

Comment: Thank you! This was so helpful!